# Combining dataframe with first 2 columns of another dataframe without changing index position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I originally have a `'monthly' DataFrame` with months (1-11) as column index and number of disease cases as values.
I have another `'disease' DataFrame` with the first 2 columns as `'Country'` and `'Province'`.
I want to combine the `'monthly' DataFrame` with the 2 columns, and the 2 columns should be still be the first 2 columns in the combined `'monthly' DataFrame` (Same index position).

In other words, the original `'monthly' DataFrame` is:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
 0   1   5   8   0   9   9   8   18   82   89   81
 1   0   1   9   19  8   12  29  19   91   74   93
```

The desired output is:

```
    Country       Province    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
 0  Afghanistan  Afghanistan  1   5   8   0   9   9   8   18   82   89   81
 1  Argentina    Argentina    0   1   9   19  8   12  29  19   91   74   93
```

I was able to append the 2 columns into the `'monthly' DataFrame` by this code:

```
monthly['Country'] = disease['Country']
monthly['Province'] = disease['Province']
```

However, this puts the 2 columns at the end of the `'monthly' DataFrame`.

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11   Country       Province
 0    1   5   8   0   9   9   8   18   82   89   81   Afghanistan  Afghanistan
 1    0   1   9   19  8   12  29  19   91   74   93   Argentina    Argentina
```

How should I improve the code **without using the insert() function** ? Can I use the `iloc` to specify the index position?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `pd.concat((disease, monthly), axis=1)` ?

Comment: Use `pd.concat((disease.iloc[:, :2], monthly), axis=1)`

Comment: Or `pd.concat((disease[['Country','Province']], monthly), axis=1) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with selecting first 2 columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), here first `:` means get all rows:

```
df = pd.concat((disease.iloc[:, :2], monthly), axis=1)
```

Or by columns names:

```
df = pd.concat((disease[['Country','Province']], monthly), axis=1)
```

Comment: That is a clear explanation. Thank you so much!